# The input authorization token can\'t serve the request. DocumentDB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

Im trying to retreive a media that i had uploaded to a row in documentdb. I'm getting the following error when i call the method using **node.js**. Can anyone provide me any pointers on what is the right way to readmedia

**The input authorization token can\'t serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign**

```
self.client.readMedia(mediaLink, function (err, mediaResponse) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    readMediaResponse(mediaResponse, function (err, mediaResult) {
        if (err) {
           console.log("Error in mediaResponse");
           console.log(err);
        }
        else
            callback(undefined, mediaResult);
    });
});

var readMediaResponse = function (response, callback) {
    var data = "";
    console.log("Respose");
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    response.on("end", function () {
        if (response.statusCode >= 300) {
            return callback({ code: response.statusCode, body: data });
        }

        return callback(undefined, data);
    });
};
```

Can anyone please provide me any pointers on how to solve this issue

Comment: Are you certain that you are using the MediaLink in the Document Attachment as opposed to the DocumentLink?

Comment: Just as a sanity check - does the auth token work for retrieving other resources (e.g. document, collection, etc.)?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone yeah im sure im using the media link

Comment: Yes im able to fetch doc information. Im not able to fetch media